# Cucumber - Using same datatable in multiple steps in a scenario

Tags: datatable, cucumber, gherkin

I am new to cucumber and trying to use the datatable in a scenario.

```
Scenario: 1. Sets the configuration and validates it  
    When the user sets the POST config  
    | key                 | value |  
    | enabled             | false |  
    | timezone            | "Asia/Kolkata" |     
    Then the user gets the config and the result is successfull  
    | key                 | value |  
    | enabled             | false |  
    | timezone            | "Asia/Kolkata" |
```

Here i am using the same datatable to construct REST post request and then validate it.

Is there a possibility to specify the same datatable for multiple steps ?
If i specify the datatable at the end of the scenario,for the first step i get the error Arity mismatch.

TIA

Comment: Just store the datatable in a variable in the "When" step in your programming language. Access the variable in the "Then" step.

Answer (score 0):

You could also provide different parameters to you test by using scenario outline.

Scenario Outline: Sets the configuration and validates it
    When the user sets the POST config with key “<*key>” and enabled status equals to “<*enabled>” for timezone “<*timezone>”
    Then the user gets the config and the correct data is recorded for key “<*key>” and enabled status equals to “<*enabled>” for timezone “<*timezone>”

Examples:

```
| key       | enabled |  timezone      |
| value     | false   |  Asia/Kolkata  |  
| value2    | true    |  timezone2     |
```

The first time your test will be run with key = value, enabled = false, timezone =  Asia/Kolkata
The second time the test will be executed with key = value2, enabled = true, timezone = timezone2 
Etc

P.S.: You need to delete the * symbols

I hope it helps.